# Download Image for Firebase Storage inside a SwiftUI Listview (contact app)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, google-cloud-storage

I'm new in Swift and I'm trying to display inside a **SwiftUI** ListView :

- some datas
- an image (linked to datas)

It's kind of a contact app.

All these datas are stored in firestore. I created a function which gives the image URL on firestore :

```
func getURL(path: String, completion: @escaping (((URL?) -> Void))) {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    storage.reference().child(path).downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
        guard let url = url, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        let urlPath = url.absoluteURL
        completion(urlPath)
    })
}
```

But when i call this function in the SwiftUI View, the following error appears :

> "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols"

There is the calling code of the function :

`getURL(path: bike.access1, completion: { path in AnimatedImage(url: path)})`

I'm aware that i can't call function inside a view, but i don't see how to manage to display an image from Firestore inside a SwiftUI List View.
If anyone know a strategy, I'm really interested.
Thanks in advance
Jean

Answer (score 3):

The completion handler is (in general) a great way of dealing with asynchronous code. But, it a `View` in SwiftUI, it's a little more common to use a @State or @Published value and then render the view conditionally based on its state.

I like using an `ObservableObject` view model for this sort of thing:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var imageURL : URL?
    
    func getURL(path: String) {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        storage.reference().child(path).downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
            guard let url = url, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            self.imageURL = url
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let url = viewModel.imageURL {
                AnimatedImage(url: url)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            viewModel.getURL(path: "URL_STRING_GOES_HERE")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that my types

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm trying this right now !